# JS : Custom design for Dragging, Dropping & Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to resolve the custom Drag, Drop & sort?
**Basic Example**

Let suppose we have a Calculator and the user is able to drag,drop & remove a block of calculator's buttons  OR any individual button.   (I have made it very successful)

**My Requirement** : I need to develop a custom application for any kind of element.Let suppose if user want to inherit Drag & Drop feature in "Currency Converter keypad" instead of calculator, then he should be able to do it without much of technical knowledge.

Comment: Surely this can be done with jQuery UI `.draggable()` and `.droppable()` ?

Comment: yes, i did that for caluclator. But i am trying to make simple application by which anyone can make it drag-able element. Suppose we have one <div> ... </div>. if we place any component inside this <div> then component should inherit the drag drop feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through http://mystuff.comze.com/calc.html

take a look source code, Javascript.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Hey, please take a look again and drag it carefully. There are three blocks Block_1 [7, 8, 9, C] : it has four buttons and can be dragged, dropped and sort within block.  Block_2 [4, 5, 6, X] : does same thing as Block_1 but you can drag Block_1 over Block_2 and vice-versa.   There is another Block_3 which has several blocks within it. the elements of Block_3 can't be drag but the Block_3 can be drag & drop over Block_1 Or Block_2.  This is not the exact solution but just a little help  to author.

Comment: @user575363: Perhaps this could be noted in the answer.

Comment: @Tomlok : Please go through that link again http://mystuff.comze.com/calc.html.  99% accuracy.